# Notice: Undefined offset: 128 in fpdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

Notice: Undefined offset: 128 in C:\xampp\htdocs\pms\report\mysql_report.php on line 92
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I am using FPDF. data contains more than 10k thats y its displaying this error . If data is 100 like that its displaying ..

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in FPDF but as the error message "says", you have an E_NOTICE triggered in C:\xampp\htdocs\pms\report\mysql_report.php on line 92.

FPDF is simply not able to send the resulting PDF because of this error.